# canvas.getHeight is equal to view.getHeight on tablet device

Tags: android, scrollview, android-canvas

i have a scroll View That i add it my custom View , in customview overwrite onMeasure & onTouchEvent but when i scroll it anything not draw .

```
  protected final void onDraw(Canvas paramCanvas)
  {     
    int text_width;
    int yCanvas;
    yCanvas = paramCanvas.getClipBounds().top;
    int h = paramCanvas.getClipBounds().height() ;
    int hView = this.getHeight() ;
    int topView = this.getTop();
    paramCanvas.drawText("text...yCanvas :"+yCanvas + " --- hCanvas:"+h   +"--- hView" + hView + " ----topView"+topView, 20, yCanvas+200, new Paint());

  }

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean res = super.onTouchEvent(event);
    postInvalidate();
    System.out.println("result: " + res);
    return res;
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {     
    int h = 1000;
    setMeasuredDimension(View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), h);}
```

The interesting thing is that in all tablet  mycanvas height is equal with view height  but in other device canvas.heigh() is exactullay equal with heigh display .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is probably, why you don't see anything being drawn.

You might want to look into your Paint object, which basically has no meaningful values set up. You could create a member variable and set all properties (color, etc) you need. Than reuse that object every time you call drawText (or another draw method).

Edit:
If the Paint object isn't the issue ;) You might need to double check the coordinates you're constructing. You are using a `ScrollView` -- so maybe it's something about that `canvas.getClipBounds`. Why not just draw the text at `0,0`?

Comment: i set this parameter but i dont reply . it work fine in other device but on tablet dont work.:(

Comment: Maybe the position is a problem? Or something about what you are doing in `onMeasure` (the fixed `1000` looks suspicious).

Comment: i draw it in position (0,0) at first time my text draw but when i scroll dont work . in emulator and other device (sony , samsung ) work fine but when i run in samsung tablet(P5100) dont work.